# Dynamic linq/lambda expression from query

Tags: linq, lambda

I have data query and want to create dynamic `linq/lambda` expression which i can run on `entity collection`. Not sure how to do this using Expression builder. Please provide some examples if possible.

For e.g I have query

> Select person.name,person.surname from person where person.name= 'Joe'

and i have **entity collection of all persons**. But dont want to fire a query instead want to convert this query in to lambda and run on **persons collection**. This to avoid server calls.

`linq/lambda` expression like

> from person in person where person.id ='Joe' select person.name;

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use method syntax rather than query syntax
for example instead of from person in people where person.Name == "Test"
use People.Where(person => person.Name == "Test");

then you can add reference to Mono.CSharp.DLL and then use Evaluator class to compile and run C# codes on the fly easily, without loosing performance too much.

Then compile and run your LINQ queries by C# strings and invoke that string with Evaluator.

You can see this method in JavaScript codes too, with eval function.

Let me know if other information are needed

Good luck

Comment: It's not related to question, but using method syntaxes are better, because they support all features of linq and are more in common in other technologies and frameworks other than linq, such as Razor helpers, moq, ....

Comment: thanks for reply .. but what if there are multiple table and required joining them and getting out the results.

Comment: You can use 'Join' method, every query syntax will be compiled into method syntax, obviously you've limited abilities of method syntax in query syntax not vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

`LINQ`

```
var xxx = from p in person 
          where p.Name equals "Joe"
          select p;
```

Lamda

```
 var lambda = Person.Where(m=> m.Name == "Joe");
```

For tutorials

[MSDN 101 LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397687.aspx)

[MSDN](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b)

[Lambda](http://forum.codecall.net/topic/65225-c-introduction-to-lambda-functions-and-linq/)